# Monitor.TryEnter equivalent in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

How to skip method if some thread owns by this method in java, i know that in .net exists `Monitor.TryEnter`, and i can accomplish that by something like this:

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter()){
 //do work
}
//else skip
```

But how can i accomplish that behavior in java, is any equivalent of `Monitor.TryEnter` in java.

Comment: Yor question is not very precise, but i guess you are looking for `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` or some of its cousins

Comment: If you can use third-party libraries, Guava does indeed have a `Monitor` type [with a `tryEnter` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Monitor.html#tryEnter()).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would [`ReentrantLock#tryLock()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28%29) work for you?

It has the behavior that you want, *but* it requires an explicit lock object and as such it does not work with the embedded Java object monitor - I do not believe that there is an equivalent to `tryLock()` for Java object monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably best off using [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

If you use a Semaphore that holds one permit :

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
```

the resulting code looks virtually the same :

```
if (semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
    try {
        // do work
    } finally {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
// else skip
```

I imagine in .Net you also have to make sure to release the lock again.